# Foreground service not working if phone goes in Idle mode

Tags: android, android-workmanager, foreground-service

Steps:

1. We are using android WorkManager
   Ref link:: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics
2. Create a notification for foreground service
3. App goes in background, we start the foreground service using:
   startForegroundService()
   Ref:: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Issues::
App goes in "Idle mode" foreground service is not working.

Correct behaviour we need:

1. App goes in background
2. App killed from background
3. Phone goes in "Idle mode"
   In above 3 case foreground service is running continue without stop.We need this functionality in all android devices.

Current Android device version and modal:
Android: 11
Modal: CPH1969

Note:: In android documentation mentioned, If start the foreground service it will be never stop If app goes in "Idle Mode".

```
String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
    createNotificationChannel();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

    Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(this, LockscreenActivity.class);
    PendingIntent fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, fullScreenIntent, 0);
    
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setTicker("Background service ticker")
            .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
            .build();
    startForeground(1, notification);
    startService(intent);
    return START_STICKY;
```

Requirement:
I need a foreground service for track the location like one location to another location.

Comment: Can you give some more details like what exactly your foreground service is doing, and some code snippet of you how are starting, stopping, binding and unbinding service.

Comment: @mohit48 I have updated the question with code
I need try my employee's time and path when they are clocked in, generally then keep the phone on side while drive to the location and in this case I am not able to track as of now. For this requirement I am trying to integrate foreground service.

Comment: how are you starting this service?

Comment: @mohit48 I am starting the service with startService(intent); just before return statement.

Comment: WorkManager is not suitable for tracking users. In that case, you should be using a Service. WorkManager is for cases where you need to do some work, you need to ensure some conditions for the work to be running, and you need to be sure that it will finish at some point for sure even after application kills, device restarts, etc.